# Getting LibreOffice (uninstalled, files only) to work on AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, dockerfile, libreoffice

I'm nearly there, but stuck at the last hurdle.

```
$ /path/to/soffice.bin --version
```

^ This works both on my local machine (Docker Container) and on (container deployed on) AWS Lambda

However,

```
    $ /path/to/soffice.bin \
        --headless --invisible --nodefault --nofirststartwizard --nolockcheck --nologo --norestore --nosplash \
        --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export \
        --outdir /tmp \
        $filename \
            2>&1 || true  # avoid exit-on-fail
```

... fails with:

> LibreOffice - dialog 'LibreOfficeDev 6.4 - Fatal Error': 'The application cannot be started.
> User installation could not be completed. 'LibreOfficeDev 6.4 - Fatal Error: The application cannot be started.
> User installation could not be completed.

Searching on google, everything is pointing towards a permissions issue with `~/.config/libreoffice`

And there is something strange going on with file permissions on the Lambda runtime.
Maybe it is attempting to read or write to a location to which it doesn't have access.

Is there any way to get it working?

Comment: Did you get this figured out? [I'm stuck on the first part of running LibreOffice in lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65884502/aws-lambda-tar-file-extraction-doesnt-seem-to-work). Do you maybe know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that lambda can only write on `/tmp`, but the default HOME is not `/tmp`

adding

```
export HOME=/tmp
```

before calling `/path/to/soffice.bin`

should do the trick.

Also, note that the first run will produce a predictable error because of unknown issues. So you should handle the retry.

(Translated using [Hero Translate](https://herotranslate.com/))